# Is it possible to create a network interface programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, uiwebview

I am trying to add an indicator to my iOS app which will be shown whenever a network call happens from my app. That means the indicator should work even an AJAX call happens from the UIWebView/WKWebView. Instead of triggering the indicator from every delegate such as UIWebViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDeleaget or NSURLSessionDelegate, etc. I want to monitor a network interface and do it. I have tried `getifaddrs()` to get the interface status/packet count. But I wasn't able to differentiate the packet that send from my app and others.

So my question is:

1. I read iOS won't support packet trace. Is it possible to
   differentiate the packets by any means?
2. Is it possible to create virtual interface programmatically and
   route all connections? So that we can use `getifaddrs()` on that
   interface.
3. Or is there any other way to achieve this (trigger the indicator
   from one single point without disturbing the entire code)?